# c# Reading a binary file in matlab and c# returns different values

Tags: c#, matlab, binaryfiles

I have a bin file which contains float32 values, 32xinf matrix array. size of the array is dependent on recording time, it can be 32x500 for a second, 32x5000 for 10 seconds and so on.

I use the code below to read the file in Matlab.

```
channels = 32;
sampleRate = 500;
fid = fopen('C:\Users\metin.senturk\Desktop\MyFile.bin', 'rb');
rawData = fread(fid, [channels, inf], 'float32');
```

In c#, I use this code to read the file.

```
float[,] floatArray = new float[1, 32];

using (BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(string.Format("{0}{1}.bin", DefaultFilePath, "MyFile"), FileMode.Open)))
{
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < floatArray.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            floatArray[i, j] = Reader.ReadSingle();
            MeanOfChannels[j] += floatArray[i, j];
        }
    }
}
```

Results are here for the first 32 values in binary file.

[Matlab Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlWXP.png)

[c# Results](http://prntscr.com/a7pvcl)

I checked the size of float32 (32 bit/4 byte) in Matlab and

> Reader.ReadSingle()

(reads 4 bytes). I also tried to use this code below.

```
BitConverter.ToSingle(Reader.ReadBytes(sizeof(float)), 0);
```

Values are not the same in Matlab and c#. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you open the file in a hex editor and post the first 16 bytes please?

Comment: Here it is "7F-D6-CC-C7-3E-E2-8F-C7-51-73-96-C7-67-A1-CD-C7" Also, you should now that the incorrect code is in c#. Matlab code gives me the correct values that I try to reach with c#.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I use [OnlineHexEditor](http://www.onlinehexeditor.com/) and the file include [these contents](http://prntscr.com/a7rb4v)

Comment: Thanks - and for the first float in that specific file, what should the number be?

Comment: I guess I found my problem. I am reading the x and y coordinates wrong while reading from binary file in for loops. Also, I have to convert to double to fix comma place in values.

Comment: Ah, well that's good. :)